# Angular Interpolation Syntax Reuse

Tags: angular

I have a template string that evaluates an Observable:

```
<button [title]="filterButtonText">
      {{ selectedUsers$ | async | delimiter:"|"}}
</button>
```

The delimiter pipe converts the string to "User1|User2" etc.
I want to use the same value in the title property like :

```
<button [title]="{{ selectedUsers$ | async | delimiter:"|"}}">
      {{ selectedUsers$ | async | delimiter:"|"}}
</button>
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I want to reuse the output of 
    `{{ selectedUsers$ | async | delimiter:"|"}}` in the title property. How can I do it? Or is there is a better of the way of achieving this without re-evaluating the observable?

**EDIT**

```
<button [title]="selectedUsers$ | async | delimiter:'|'">
  {{ selectedUsers$ | async | delimiter:"|"}}
</button>
```

Removing {{ }} worked. But another question, is there a way I can evaluate this in one place ? Without having the same statement in two places ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse the title of the button to set its content, with the help of a template reference variable:

```
<button #btn [title]="selectedUsers$ | async | delimiter:'|'">
  {{ btn.title }}
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Precisely what I was looking for.